# In gnome some for applications the window shadow counts as resize area

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gtk

I have an Arch Linux installation with gnome 40.4 and gtk2 (2.24.33), gtk3 (3.24.30) and gtk4 (4.4.0) installed. (Graphicbackend is X11 if that's relevant)

For some applications - probably those that use gtk3 - (like Thunderbird, Firefox, VSCode) the drop shadow of the window counts to the resize area for the window (which is roughly 60px).

For other Applications (like Chromium, Settings, Nautilus) the shadow doesn't count to the resize area, which is the behavior I would expect.

The Theme used is Adwaita but that behavior also exits for other themes.

Does anyone know what the reason for this could be and how that could be changed?

Having a 60px large area around the window one cannot be click-through is a bit annoying.

Comment: Cannot say for Arch Linux, but on Debian and Fedora the resize cursor activates when I hover anywhere in a window shadow. So, I would say that it is the expected behaviour. Checked in Debian for VSCode too. Adwaita is the default theme and the shadow does not seem too big to me on my laptop.